# Find how many entry match in same table PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, count, matching

I'm looking to find with COUNT or something like that how many entries are the same in a TABLE like that :

```
id | skills
1    cooking
2    swimming
3    sports
4    cooking
```

So I already have two loops to match like this :

```
1/2
1/3
1/4

2/3
2/4

3/4
```

But I want that during matching I use a query which tell me for 1/4 that there is one common skills.

edit: I will clarify what I already have.

So the matching table look like this :

```
id | idUser1 | idUser2 | MatchingScore
1       1        2           50
2       1        3           75
3       1        4           10
4       2        3           25
5       2        4           75
6       3        4           05
```

Now I want to generate the matchingScore by calculating how many skills they have in common in the first TABLE. Example :

```
id | skills
1    cooking, swimming
2    cooking, driving
3    swimming, sports
4    cooking, swimming
```

The goal to the query I'm looking for is to take cooking, and swimming of id 1 and compare with cooking and driving from id 2 and tell me : "1". So basically I just want to compare how many same entries there is.

Comment: I don't completely follow how the output comes from the input table provided.  Can you explain the output?

Comment: Check the edit part

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I have understood what you need.

In my query table t `JOIN` with itself `ON t1.id < t2.id` and if t1.skills = t2.skills common_skills take value 1 else 0:

```
SELECT t1.id::text || '/' || t2.id::text,
       CASE WHEN t1.skills = t2.skills THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS common_skills
FROM t AS t1
INNER JOIN t AS t2 ON t1.id < t2.id
ORDER BY t1.id, t2.id;
```

With your input data and my query I get:

| matching | common_skills |
| --- | --- |
| 1/2 | 0 |
| 1/3 | 0 |
| 1/4 | 1 |
| 2/3 | 0 |
| 2/4 | 0 |
| 3/4 | 0 |

**UPDATED** (after question requirements changed):

```
SELECT row_number() OVER (ORDER BY t1.id, t2.id), 
       t1.id AS idUser1, 
       t2.id AS idUser2, 
       t1.skills || ', ' || t2.skills AS skills,
       '?' AS MatchingScore
FROM t AS t1
INNER JOIN t AS t2 ON t1.id < t2.id
ORDER BY t1.id, t2.id;
```

| row_number | iduser1 | iduser2 | skills | matchingscore |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2 | cooking, swimming | ? |
| 2 | 1 | 3 | cooking, sports | ? |
| 3 | 1 | 4 | cooking, cooking | ? |
| 4 | 2 | 3 | swimming, sports | ? |
| 5 | 2 | 4 | swimming, cooking | ? |
| 6 | 3 | 4 | sports, cooking | ? |

If you have more than one skill per id (first table in your question, I called it "t") and table t `JOIN` with itself `ON t1.id < t2.id`, then you want count skills in common per match (row) you can use this query:

```
SELECT row_number() OVER (ORDER BY t1.id, t2.id), 
       t1.id AS idUser1, 
       t2.id AS idUser2, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN t1.skills = t2.skills THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS common_skills
FROM t AS t1
INNER JOIN t AS t2 ON t1.id < t2.id
GROUP BY t1.id, t2.id
ORDER BY t1.id, t2.id;
```

Result (with your example data in first table):

| row_number | iduser1 | iduser2 | common_skills |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2 | 0 |
| 2 | 1 | 3 | 0 |
| 3 | 1 | 4 | 1 |
| 4 | 2 | 3 | 0 |
| 5 | 2 | 4 | 0 |
| 6 | 3 | 4 | 0 |

Comment: Hey thanks for that but it's not really what i'm looking for, a while ago I already saw a query using ```COUNT()``` but don't find it now. Btw check the edited part for more details

Comment: Your are welcome! I don't understand how you calculate MatchingScore. Where do you get "driving" skill?, it is not present in first table.

Comment: the second table with skills is just the more details one of the first. MatchingScore is actually random but the goal is to get the number of skills in common with COUNT() and also the total number of skills of the first user to match. With that I will be able to calculate the matchingScore.

Comment: You should share a [minimal consistent example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that let me understand the problem (not random values) and the desired result with that example data. You said "get the number of skills in common" in common with what? what do you compare? how do you calculate matching score (formula).

Comment: Okay so actually the matchingScore is really random I use this to generate it : ```SELECT floor(random() * 10 + 35)::INT INTO random;``` and i need to know how many skills in commons for two users like I would like to do something like that : ```COUNT(skills in common) FROM "WU_Users" WHERE "id" = 1 AND "id" = 2;``` I don't know if you understand with that. we just compare the two lists of skills from selected users and check how many skills are in common and we return the number of skills in common.

Comment: It seems that a user has more than one skill, not just one like in your example. I updated my answer with a new query.

Comment: Not what I want tbh it should return 2 for the row_number 3 coz there have 2 skills in common not one

Comment: What are the two skill in common? In your example (first table) id 1 has only one skill "cooking" and id 4 has one skill "cooking" (so they have one skill in common: "cooking"). If you want that each coincidence sum two you can do: `SUM(CASE WHEN t1.skills = t2.skills THEN 2 ELSE 0 END) AS common_skills`